# Where do design questions belong?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, subjective

Recently I've wanted to ask a few design questions, which are by definition subjective/argumentative. I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5055824/suggest-your-thoughts-on-this-design) recently which appears to be the kind of question I would ask.

Do these belong on Stack Overflow, or Programmers.SE, or not in Stack Exchange at all?

If you do not think it belongs in either, than is an Area51 proposal for Software Design a possibility?

Comment: I think there is a Code Review SE site... would it fit there?

Comment: @George, no cause it's not really code; it's more of an architecture/how-should-I-do-this type of thing

Comment: Probably Programmers.SE then.

Answer (score 1):

I think it depends a lot on the question, and how specific the question is. if it's for the design of *a specific algorithm*, I think StackOverflow is best. If it's for the logical design of an entire program or a large chunk, I vote programmers. If it's more subjective, again I think probably programmers.

To illustrate this pint, the StackOverflow FAQ states:

> What kind of questions can I ask here?
>
> Stack Overflow is for professional and
>   enthusiast programmers, people who
>   write code because they love it. We
>   feel the best Stack Overflow questions
>   have a bit of source code in them, but
>   if your question generally covers …
>
> - a specific programming problem
> - **a software algorithm**
> - [...]
>
> … then you’re in the right place to ask your question!

*Programmer's* FAQ states:

> What kind of questions can I ask here?
>
> Programmers - Stack Exchange is for
>   expert programmers who are interested
>   in subjective questions on software
>   development.
>
> This can include topics such as:
>
> - [...]
> - Algorithm and data
>     structure concepts
> - Design patterns
> - Architecture
> - [...]
>
> All subjective questions are expected to be constructive. How do we define that? Constructive subjective questions …
>
> - inspire answers that explain “why” and “how”.
>
> [...]
>
> **If your question is about …**
>
> - **Specific programming problem, software algorithms, coding,** ask on Stack Overflow.